# How do I deal with unusual characters in my CSS?

Tags: html, css, unicode, wget

I'm referring to the following file

http://yabe.ayafish.com/static/stylesheets/crudify.css

If I link to it directly then the following code

```
.crudSortedAsc:after {
    content: 'â–¼';
}
```

Appears as an up arrow.  If I try to download it through wget and use it locally the raw text appears instead of the arrow.  How can I get the arrow to appear whilst running the style sheet locally?

Comment: are you trying to display the unicode that is in content:""; ? i mean the three separate characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the CSS file contains just two special characters, the simplest and most robust way is to represent them using CSS escape notations. They work independently of character encoding. For '▼' use '\25BC' and for '▲' use '\25B2'.

There are many ways to use such characters directly in CSS, but then the encoding of the file must be correct (in practice, UTF-8) and it must be properly declared in an HTTP header, in a `@charset` rule in CSS, or in a `charset` attribute of the `link` element that refers to the CSS file. And you would need to make sure that your setting is not overridden; for example, an HTTP header overrides the other settings.

Answer (score 2):

add  `@charset "UTF-8";` on the top of you css file.

Answer (score 1):

This is an encoding problem. Somewhere along the stops in the way, something is not UTF8. That stop is your problematic one, fix it, and you should get your arrow.

Comment: Might also be the browser defaulting to iso-8859-1 etc. instead of utf8.

Comment: Yes. If you look at the css file with the browser and force the encoding as UTF-8, the arrows show up normally.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly an encoding issue.

To clarify, the browser and the css-file needs to be communicating in the same encoding or the same entities will be rendered differently. The standard is utf-8, but the important issue isn't really which is used but that it is used uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different editor.  I've found that several editors out there have this issue and you don't realize the characters are there till you check the css after it's put on the server (can't see it in your editor.)  I use [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) and I haven't had any further issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem once with funky characters in my css, what fixed it was resaving the stylesheet as UTF8 and not as "UTF8 Without BOM" in notepad++ and that fixed the issue. You can always try to define the encoding on the top most part of the stylesheet:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```